# Unity 2D background does not fit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a background image, but after getting the apk, it doesn't work like it is in the unity game engine.

How can I fix it? After getting the apk, I want the size to fit the screen exactly.

Phone:[image]

Unity: 1. Image [image] 2.image [image]

Canvas Setting: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Canvas Scaler` > `Screen Match Mode` to `Expand`.
It will fit the image on width and height, expanding empty space if necessary.

Comment: i did that but the spawner is not visible how can i fix it (image: https://ibb.co/gSTHQfp)